# Android AVD install chrome and firefox

Tags: android, firefox, google-chrome, sdk, android-virtual-device

I created few AVD's using the AVD Manager. I want to know how can I install chrome/firefox on these AVD's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Chrome's .apk](http://www.apkfiles.com/apk-11/google-chrome)

[Firefox's .apk](http://www.androiddrawer.com/7745/download-firefox-browser-for-android-17-0-app-apk/#.UUmWtVeFWN0)

Download both .apk files and install to your AVD using `adb install apk_name`

Comment: keep patience during installation is it may take couple of minutes to perform installation :)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I downloaded the .apk files. Is adb install a command on terminal? Can u write exact instruction?

Comment: **adb** command is in your android sdk's folder called **platform-tools** (for e.g. `C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe`). Move the downloaded apk file to that folder, open command prompt and move to that folder's location and execute the abive given command by changing the last part to downloaded file's name. apk stands for Android PacKage

Comment: I did, it says command not found. I can see adb file in the platform-tools folder. I have stored the .apk file in this folder and I am in the platform-tools folder only

Comment: are you sure you are doing it correctly? because it works at my side and i just installed Firefox in one of my AVD

Comment: Thanks Waqas, What is the AVD setting for installing firefox and chrome. I have the following avd files chrome (com.android.chrome-2.apk) and firefox (fennec-10.0.3esr.multi.android-arm.apk)

Comment: Where can I find .apk files for the current latest releases?

Comment: Dead link for chrome's .apk

Comment: even if you install that, when you open chorme you get a dialog "some functionality is missing from android" and then it closes.

Comment: @gcb perhaps your device doesn't ogffer all the features required to run that application

Comment: @Waqas everyone here is talking about the emulator not devices. and i'm using the 'default' when creating AVDs. I actually opened another question to find out exactly what the emulator should be configured with to run chrome... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62147/

Answer (score 1):

To install something onto a device, you need to already have the device running.

So first, start the device using the emulator command.

Then, in a different terminal/command window, use the adb command to install the package. In my case, I've copied the apk file to the platform-tools folder:

```
./adb install Firefox_17.0.apk
```

Like the rest of the emulator, the installation is slow, so be patient.

Of course, this just installs the packages. Getting them to run successfully is another matter entirely. So far, I cannot get the Chrome or Firefox packages to run. Chrome says "Not supported on this version of Android. Version 4.0 is minimal supported version." I am running 4.3 in the emulator. And Firefox starts but then immediately terminates with a "Unfortunately, Firefox has stopped" message.

Answer (score 0):

Get the apk files and install them through adb (adb install .apk.

Comment: What should be the avd setting for it to support mozilla firefox. Cant i simply run install it from this link? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox I can download the .apk file. Can you post step by step instruction to install it from the terminal. I havent used terminal much on my mac. thanks!